# How to facilitate `soft delete` of data while facilitating `physical delete` as well?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database with tables where some of they are interconnected with foreign keys. Well, you can check below for an example.

[image]

I need to make sure both parent-child can be deleted if required. But I also need to make sure the system will perform a *soft delete* (just mark as *deleted* without physically deleting them) so we can restore the data or use them for analysis.

1. I know I can delete both parent-child easily by enabling `ON DELETE CASCADE`. But here I may lose thousands of data forever and will not be able to restore. It will be a mess if the delete is accidental.
2. I know I can disable the `ON DELETE CASCADE` and add another field to database tables to mark records `deleted`. So if a record is deleted it will simply be marked as deleted and will not display in application while they will be presented in database. The issue in this scenario is, if a `parent` is marked as deleted, then I will have to mark all `children` as deleted as well, at least in my system. From the other hand, it will be a pretty big mess if I physically want to delete records, I will have to delete all `child` records first.

So what should be the better option? I am not really interested in over complicating by making shadow tables, archive tables, view etc as well.

The best option I can think of is as below.

1. Enable `DELETE ON CASCADE`. But do not expose record `delete` methods to general users. Expose these methods only to admins.
2. Add `delete_flag` field to tables. This field will mark whether a record is deleted or not. Expose these methods to both general users and admins as it will physically not delete anything.

Please let me know whether this way is good or you have better options? Also if my way is better, how to update the `delete_flag` of the child when parent's `delete_flag` has changed?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland as far as I can see, the PO is talking about a table with products info and a table about categories of those products. It doesn't have any  individuals' personal data, so the **GDPR** doesn't apply because it only applies to personal data, not for products data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I handle this sort of thing.

1. Avoiding CASCADE CONSTRAINT,
2. I put an `expiry_datestamp` column on each table.
3. I set up the live-data queries to say `AND (expiry_datestamp IS NULL OR expiry_datestamp < NOW())`
4. When soft-deleting rows, I use `UPDATE ... SET expiry_datestamp = NOW()`
5. That leaves the ability to look at the data and see what was recently soft-deleted and when.
6. I create purge programs to DELETE expired stuff, by DELETEing child records explicitly before parent records. (Not relying on CASCADE CONSTRAINT functionality). These programs can be run monthly or weekly, or at whatever schedule you need.
7. The `(x IS NULL OR x < NOW())` filter can be simplified if you set the expiry_date values in new records to a particular date far in the future.

Note. You can certainly use a `deleted` column instead of my more complex `expiry_date` approach. *If you do*, make sure your queries say `AND deleted = 0` rather than `AND deleted <> 1`.  Inequality filters don't perform as well as equality filters.

About GDPR: It's a real concern, and a pain in the neck. If your policy says you delete personally identifiable information three months after a user last enters it, then you can make your purge programs handle that operation.  You are correct that product information isn't personal information.

**Edit**: My procedure:  I don't like to grant the web app user the MySQL privileges to hard-DELETE rows, only to soft-DELETE them. It's more secure, in my workflow, to do that in a purge job with higher privileges.  I avoid CASCADE CONSTRAINTS because I don't like side-effects: I want to catch and stop DELETEs (or UPDATEs) when they violate constraints. I believe it's more secure and better programming practice to create my purge procedures to remove dependent rows explicitly.

You may have different preferences.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So why you avoid `cascade` while it can ease up everything? In my case, the data will be deleted manually via GUI program when required, no automated processes.

Regarding GDPR, do not worry, no issue like that. The user has options to `delete` or `deactivate`. `delete` means physical delete and `deactivate` means soft delete.